# Cannot use //TODO flag in MonoDevelop (OS X version)

Tags: monodevelop, todo

I am having trouble using the `//TODO` flag. When I put the `//TODO` comment in my code, it doesn't show the corresponding task in the task list.

Has anyone run into the same problem before? If so, how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression in MonoDevelop 3.0. It's fixed in MonoDevelop 3.0.3 which is currently in beta.